# Intuition behind defining the information of a random variable as being additive for independent events

Tags: statistics, information-theory, statistical-mechanics, fisher-information, information-geometry

I'm recently studying the concepts of entropy and I've a fundamental question regarding the conceptual formulation of information content of a random variable $X$, or equivalently, the uncertaintly of a system/probabilistic experiments with $n$ possible outcomes. In either cases, I'm trying to understand why the information content, or, the uncertainty has to be an additive function in the formulation process itself? Of course, $f(p) :=k log p$ satisfies the $f(pq)= f(p) + f(q)$. But my question is before defining the information content or uncertaintly as a log function. More precisely:

(1) Information content (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)): Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where the three notations in the parentheses denote respectiveky the sample space, a sigma algebra of $P$-measurable sets ("events"), and $P$ is the probability measure on $\Omega$. Now, we don't quite need a random variable to formulate the information content $I$, i.e. $I$ is just a function defined on the "events", $I : \mathcal{F} \to [0, \infty]$, so that:

(1) $I(\Omega)=0$ (This is intutively clear, as the full event doesn't bring us any information),

(2) $I(A) \leq I(B)$ if $P(A) \geq P(B)$ (intuitively clear, as rarer events are more informative), and

**(3) $I(AB)=I(A) + I(B)$, where $A,B$ are independent. Now, this is the part I fail to have an intuition: why is it assumed that $I(AB)=I(A) + I(B)$, where $A,B$ are independent?**

Let's try to examine some counter examples here. If we'd have assumed $I(AB)=I(A)I(B)$, where $A,B$ are independent, then it'd not necessaily satisfy (2), as there're events $A,B$ with one of $I(A), I(B)$ is less than $1$, and then $I(A) \leq I(AB) = I(A)I(B) > I(A)$, contradintion. So this doesn't work.

**What if, we'd have defined $I(AB) = I(A) + I(B) + \phi(I(A), I(B))$, where $\phi(.,.)$ satisfies: i) $\phi(p, 1) = 0 \forall p, \phi(1, q)=0 \forall q, ii) \phi(p,q) = \phi(q, p) \forall p, q $. What'd be the problem if the information content were defined like this?**

I understand the last definition looks unnecessarily complicated, so perhaps counterintuitive, and also, perhaps Shannon was inspired by the idea of entropy in thermodynamics, but still I wonder!

Comment: You might find it interesting to read this - https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350/2008/lectures/06a/lecture-06a.pdf . Essentially, the view espoused is a pragmatc one: the set of axioms itself doesn't really matter, and one can think of other reasonable ones. What's important is the definition it yields, and how useful that concept is. Independently of this small set of rules, (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) we know that Shannon entropy is a very useful concept. So in a sense the reason these axioms are interesting is because they give rise to entropy. Note that this is *not* circular - the concept of entropy and its importance precedes these axioms (this is, of course, common in the discovery of maths, although it isn't always presented this way).